# too many open files when saving tiff images with PIL.Image and tiff_lzw compression

Tags: python, image, compression, python-imaging-library, tiff

When saving several tif images using the PIL.Image.save function and tiff_lzw compression I get the
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files error.

The error happens after saving 8187 images.
The error does not happen if no compression (or compression = "raw") is used.
The same error happens if using another compression method (I tried "tiff_adobe_deflate" as well)

The error can be reproduced by running this code.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

fn = "test.tif"
compression = "tiff_lzw"

for i in range(10000):
    a = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
    with Image.fromarray(a) as rawtiff:
        rawtiff.save(fn, compression = compression)
        rawtiff.close()
```

In this code I used a context manager and I also tried to explicitely close the Image object. The error still persists.

Tested on Windows;
Python version: 3.10.6;
Pillow version: 9.2.0

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're running? I tried it and, unsurprisingly, got **TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), <i8** [ Pillow 9.4.0, Python 3.11.1 ]

Comment: I'm getting an error, this is the stack trace ```mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]

KeyError: ((1, 1), '<i8')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/deletemethis/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    with Image.fromarray(a) as rawtiff:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/the-box/Github/watchers-alerts/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3083, in fromarray
    raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), <i8```

Comment: @Pingu: thanks for the fast reply. I could run the code exactly at it is in both my Jupyter notebook and Spyder. It works until i = 8186 before I get the "too many open files error". Maybe the error is due to different packages/python versions?

Comment: Try `print(a.dtype)` with your existing code. And also changing creation to `a = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]], np.uint8)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thanks for the hint. a.dtype = dtype('int32')
Now I changed my code as well. I hope this helps reproducing the error.

Comment: This has been opened as a Pillow issue. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6985